# Transitions, I am confused

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a layout that includes transitions on, and they go into that transition smoothly but go back to the first position abruptly once the cursor is off the selected area.

```
}
#holder div:hover {
    width:92px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all .4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all .4s ease-out;
    transition:all .4s ease-out;
```

That is the coding of it, would anyone be able to help me with getting it to back to original form smoothly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This selector only matches when a `div` that is a child of `#holder` is `:hover`ed.

```
#holder div:hover {
    background-color: #DDD;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    width: 92px;
}
```

Which means that your transitions only apply when the div is hovered. As soon as you've stopped hovering, the transitions no longer apply, and the style will jump back.

To get it to work both ways, you need to put the transition declarations on `#holder div`:

```
#holder div {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
#holder div:hover {
    background-color: #DDD;
    width: 92px;
}
```